# Как можно подключить скрипт python к html

Tags: python, html

Не получается подключить скрипт питона к html через brython, в чём проблема или как ещё можно подключить?
html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="brython.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="brython()">

<script type="text/python" src="PyQt5.py"></script>
<script type="text/python" src="parser.py"></script>
<input id="zone">
<button id="echo">click !</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А что, `PyQt` может прямо через `html` работать? Что-то я сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, это будет зависеть от того, что вы хотите сделать. Я лично использую CGI, и может быть проще, если ваши входные данные с веб-страницы будут простыми, а обучение займет меньше времени. Вот несколько ресурсов для этого:

cgi — поддержка общего интерфейса шлюза
Python — CGI-программирование
Однако вам, возможно, все же придется выполнить некоторые настройки, чтобы разрешить запуск программы вместо ее отображения.

Вот учебник по этому вопросу: Учебник по Apache: Динамический контент с CGI